# Properties file with special characters

Tags: java

I load Properties from ini file:

```
input = new FileInputStream("props.ini");
Properties prop = new Properties();
prop.load(input);
```

I need to write some special char in key that I can do only in HEX representation to `props.ini` file. Something like:

```
AAA\x41=0
```

with `A` instead of `\x41`

How to achieve that?

I use java 1.4 and can't change this.

Comment: Just use `\u`, e.g. `\u0041`.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the escaping mechanism used by `Properties.load()` is explained in detail in the API documentation of [`Properties.load()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#load-java.io.Reader-).